# Understanding User-Defined Conversions for Unrelated Types

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a class, `UDataChunk`, which is a wrapper class for all my data types (actor info like location, stats, etc).`UDataChunk` holds a `Value()` method which is hidden by derived classes in order to return the type they hold (as the data types they hold can vary, I believe that means I shouldn't use a template on `UDataChunk`?).

I have an interface, `IDataMapInterface`, which is applied to any class which can hold a `Map<TSubclassOf<UDataChunk>, UDataChunk*>`(in Unreal Engine, I believe `TSubclassOf` is the equivalent of `std::is_base_of`). The template method here is `TObjectPtr<T> DataChunk()`.

Currently, in order to get the proper data I need, I call `DataChunk<DataChunkDerivedClass>()->Value()` which is the hidden method that returns the proper data type I actually want to use (such as an actor pointer, int, vector, etc).

I'm in the middle of refactoring, and was wondering if I could do an operator overload which converts the `TObjectPtr<T> DataChunk()` implicitly to the value type it holds?

```cpp
class USenseComponent;

UCLASS(BlueprintType, EditInlineNew)

class USenseComponentChunk : public UActorComponentChunk
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:

    USenseComponentChunk()
    {
    }

    TObjectPtr<USenseComponent> Value() const { return Cast<USenseComponent>(component.Get()); } //Component is a UActorComponent*, which USenseComponent derives from

    operator TObjectPtr<USenseComponent>() const { return Cast<USenseComponent>(component.Get()); } //Component is a UActorComponent*, which USenseComponent derives from

    operator USenseComponent*() const { return Cast<USenseComponent>(component.Get()); }
};
```

As I understand it, `USenseComponentChunk*` should be implicitly converted in a situation like `TObjectPtr<USenseComponent> comp = DataChunk<USenseComponentChunk>();`, yet I receive an error:

> No User-Defined Conversion

I also experimented to try and further grasp user-defined conversions by `USenseComponent* comp = DataChunk<USenseComponentChunk>().Get()`, where `.Get()` returns `USenseComponentChunk*`, and this results in an error:

> A Value of type USenseComponentChunk* cannot be used to initialize Type USenseComponent*

So, what am I misunderstanding, or missing entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you are trying to assign a `TObjectPtr<USenseComponentChunk>` object to a `TObjectPtr<USenseComponent>` object.  Your conversion operator for that purpose is implemented in `USenseComponentChunk`, not in `TObjectPtr`.  So, unless `TObjectPtr<T>` uses [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to derive from `T`, the compiler is correct to fail the conversion.

In the second case, you are trying to assign a pointer type `USenseComponentChunk*` to an unrelated pointer type `USenseComponent*`.  So the compiler is correct to fail this conversion, too.  Since conversion operators apply to objects, not pointers, you would have to dereference the `USenseComponentChunk*` pointer in order for the compiler to invoke the `USenseComponent*` conversion operator on the `USenseComponentChunk` object, eg:

```cpp
USenseComponent* comp = *(DataChunk<USenseComponentChunk>().Get());
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling I was completely missing something.

Edit:
DataChunk<T> is a templated function in an interface, not a class. So returning an object by reference would solve the issue? I don't intend to change the functionality as I'd prefer to return a pointer, mainly just so I better understand.

Comment: This was what I lacked an understanding of by the way, "Since conversion operators apply to objects, not pointers"